# Removing Tomcat application context from URL using Apache HTTPD reverse proxy

Tags: apache, tomcat, reverse-proxy, virtualhost

We are trying to eliminate application context from the URL, but it doesn't work. The Apache web server is fronting the Tomcat server running the Java applications, and Apache virtual host is presented below:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName                          my.domain.com

   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/some.cer
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/some.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/someother.cer

   ProxyPreserveHost on
   Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;Secure;SameSite=None

   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
   RewriteRule (.*) /app1/ [R=301]

   ProxyPass            /app1/    ajp://192.168.1.123:9101/app1/
   ProxyPassReverse     /app1/    ajp://192.168.1.123:9101/app1/

</VirtualHost>
```

Multiple applications are deployed via Tomcat Manager, and every application has a dedicated subdomain. We do not want to change the application context to ROOT.

What should be done to prevent application context from appearing in the URL? For example, we want to access the application via *my.domain.com* instead of *my.domain.com/app1*. Removing the path from **ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse** didn't help.

The solution with rewrite mode that redirects my.domain.com to  my.domain.com/app1 is not applicable because the goal is to prevent context appearance (app1) in any case.

Comment: _We do not want to change the application context to ROOT._ Then you will be fighting against this particular problem for the remainder of your time on this project. Re-mapping URLs between reverse-proxies and servlet containers results in a lot of wasted time and half-working solutions. I've _never_ seen it done correctly, or completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"We do not want to change the application context to ROOT"*: I am afraid that is what you need to do. To correctly generate hyperlinks servlet applications need [`HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/http/httpservletrequest#getContextPath()) to return the correct value. Therefore you:

- either deploy each application in the root context of their own virtual host. This requires you to change the `server.xml` file to contain:

  ```xml
  <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="app1.example.com">
      <Host name="app1.example.com" appBase="webapps/app1.example.com">
      ...
      </Host>
      <Host name="app2.example.com" appBase="webapps/app2.example.com">
      ...
      </Host>
  </Engine>
  ```

  and deploy the first application as `webapps/app1.example.com/ROOT.war`, etc.
- or write a [`Valve`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Valve.html) or [`Filter`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/filter) that wraps the `HttpServletRequest` and returns the empty `""` as context path.

Since the first solution is easy to deploy, I don't know any `Valve` nor `Filter` that implements the second solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Our current deployment process depends on Tomcat Manager and uptime. so we are not able to add hosts to the engine. Your answer clarifies our options.

Comment: Tomcat has also a _"Host Manager"_ application that can manage hosts.